# Google Search Engine showing results for different keywords instead of typed one?

Tags: search, google-play-services, search-engine, google-search

Whenever I want to search for my Android APPS which are developed under publisher Nixion (suppose it). Instead of displaying that APPS developed by Nixion, it displays other keyword contents. Same thing happens with me when I search on PlayStore. Is there any thing provided so that I can request Google to include this word as keyword in PlayStore & Web Search Engine.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Is there any thing provided so that I can request Google to include this word as keyword in PlayStore & Web Search Engine.**

Yes, you may refer to this [guide](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2453980?hl=en) for the steps on how to add, edit, or remove your keywords.

And in addition to that, you may want to also check this [article](http://searchengineland.com/how-google-instant-autocomplete-suggestions-work-62592) for more information regarding how suggestions can vary by Region and Language and most of all how Google instant’s Autocomplete suggestions work.

Comment: Hi,@Teyam I am new Android Developer. I want to know How I can request Google to include any word as keyword in PlayStore? It will be very helpful for me. Please can you guide me further How to do it? I have gone through article and guide provided by you,but I am not able to get what is actual procedure to do this. Thanks for the help @Teyam !!!